# Toolbar Material Icon as status indicator

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to use a Material Icon as a status icon in the title bar.  The function addMaterialCommandToRightBar puts it on there but it looks and acts like a button.  I tried doing it using addCommandToRightBar and styling it after the Title style but it still appears like a button and can be toggled.  I'd like it more like a label and to be able to change it.  My goal is to have a connection status icon I can change easily.

Answer (score 1):

Last minute thought resulted in the answer.

```
f.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_WARNING, f.getToolbar().getTitleComponent().getStyle()), null).setEnabled(false);
```

I was missing the setEnabled on the end.  Without this it always have the border and button action.

Comment: Add material command returns a Command instance too. You can also use `findCommandComponent` on the toolbar to get a reference to the button matching the given command